# Tkinter full screen atribute not working in 3.11.2 but ok in 3.10

Tags: python-3.x

I have programed a small app in python and tkinter using pycharm on a linux machine. The machine is running 3.10, everything works just fine. When I try to run it on a Raspbery pi which claims to be running 3.11.2 there are some problems, in particular the

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1024x600+0+0")
#Full Screen Window
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

results in a small window in the center of the screen (a 1024x600 touch screen)not full screen.
There also seems to be a problem with the focus transferring to a popup windows in touch mode but not mouse cursor.
Can this be a version problem, or is it a R pi problem?